# Why isn't my PHP connecting to my database or displaying an error?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am creating a form that will take a person's name and email and see if the email exists in the database already but I can't get the database to be selected. The mysql_error() won't display the error either. Is there something wrong with my code for selecting the database? All it shows is the hardcoded text "Could not select database because" then nothing. I replaced all the variables associated with the database with random fillers so as not to give away my info but everything I have is correct regarding that.

```
$host = "host";
$user = "user";
$password = "pass";
$database = "db";
$port = xxxx;
$table = "table";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $database, $port);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
echo "Connection Successful";

mysqli_select_db($database) 
    or die("Could not select database because".mysqli_error());


// check if the username is taken
$check = "select email from $table where email = '".$_POST['email']."';"; 
$qry = mysqli_query($check) 
    or die ("Could not match data because ".mysqli_error());
$num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($qry); 

if ($num_rows != 0) { 
    echo "Sorry, there the username $username is already taken.";
}
```

Comment: u can use localhost ya own server

Comment: Your output should have *Connection Successful* as well.

Answer (score 0):

Don't call `mysqli_select_db`. You've already selected your database with the fourth parameter to `mysqli_connect`.

You only need to call `mysqli_select_db` if you want to access a *different* database after the connection has been established.

Also, Raptor is correct that if you call procedural `mysqli_error()` you must pass it a connection handle.

Answer (score 0):

For Procedural style `mysqli_error()`, you must supply the MySQLi DB link as parameter:

```
mysqli_select_db($database) 
or die("Could not select database because" . mysqli_error($conn));
```

But it's useless to call `mysqli_select_db()` as you already specified the DB schema in `mysqli_connect()`.

Additionally, your SQL is vulnerable to SQL Injection attack. Always escape the parameter before putting into SQL statement, or use prepared statements.

Comment: Ok I got past that error but now when I enter an email into the form that already exists in the database I get the error "could not match data because " which comes after the query. What is wrong with the code checking the email and cross-referencing that with the emails already in the database?

Comment: Debug by echoing the `$check` and see the resultant SQL statement.

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
<?php
$username = "your_name";
$password = "your_password";
$hostname = "localhost"; 

//connection to the database
$dbhandle = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password) 
  or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");
echo "Connected to MySQL<br>";
?>
```

Comment: Never ever use deprecated `mysql_*` functions ! Use MySQLi / PDO instead.